# How to display a picture bigger when using the angular-modal-gallery-v7

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using angular-modal-gallery Version 7.

I need to display the picture bigger [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Aoe.jpg)

My template code is :

```
     <ks-modal-gallery [id]="200" 
     [modalImages]="arrayImage" 
     [plainGalleryConfig]="plainGalleryRow" 
     [currentImageConfig]="{description: {strategy: 2, imageText: ''}}"
     [previewConfig]="{visible: true, size: {width: 'auto', height: 'auto'}}"
     [slideConfig]="{infinite: true, sidePreviews: {show: false}}"
     [dotsConfig]="{visible: false}">
     </ks-modal-gallery>
```

and my component code is :

```
     plainGalleryRow: PlainGalleryConfig = {
     strategy: PlainGalleryStrategy.ROW,
     layout: new LineLayout({ width: '0px', height: '0px' }, { length: 2, wrap: true }, 'flex-start')
     };
```

Please Can anyone help find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Angular Modal Gallery v7 is a library for creating modal image galleries in Angular. To display a picture bigger, you can increase the size of the modal window that contains the image. Here's a sample code that shows how to do this:

```js
<ks-modal-image [id]="0" [modalImages]="images" [conf]="conf"></ks-modal-image>


<ng-template #customFooter let-data="data">
  <div style="background-color: #000; padding: 10px; width: 100%; text-align: center">
    <img [src]="data.img" [alt]="data.description" style="width: 500px; height: auto">
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

In this example, the customFooter template sets the width of the displayed image to 500px. You can adjust the width and height to achieve the desired display size.

Comment: Could you give me more details please ? Because I didn't understand the relation between ks-modal-image and <ng-template #customFooter let-data="data">